# 結果が小数となる演算結果をシェルの printf コマンドで表示したい

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript

10÷100＝0.1 です。これをシェルの `printf` コマンドで出力しようと思って以下の通り実行すると結果は `0.000000` と表示されてしまいます。

```sh
printf "%f" $((10/100))
    
0.000000
```

どうすれば `0.100000` と表示できるでしょうか？（あくまで、10, 100 は変数に入れて計算するので、`%f` に渡す値を自分で計算して0.1と入れるのはなしでお願いします。）

予測ですが、多分 `10/100` が整数部分の `0` しか返してないと思いました。
C言語とかなら型宣言できますけど、シェルってどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: bash の計算式  arithmetic expansion(`$(())`) は整数演算にしか対応していないのです。。。ちなみに zsh では浮動小数点数に対応していますので `printf "%f"  $((10.0/100))` とすれば期待通りの結果を得られます。

Comment: 物によってはサポートしているようですね。[How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786) だからどのshellを使うかによるでしょう。

Comment: @metropolis なるほど。この演算式が小数点をカバーしておらず、zshだったらカバーしているのですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[シェルbash で小数の計算するコマンド](https://takuya-1st.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/03/11/012908)によると算術式展開や`expr`、`let`などの代わりに`bc`コマンドを使うと良いようです。
以下のような感じになります。

```sh
$ printf "%f" $(echo "scale=1; 10 / 100" | bc)
0.100000
```

Answer (score 1):

別解として、bash に拘らなければ例えば Perl のワンライナーで以下のように記述することが出来ます。

```perl
$ perl -e 'printf "%f\n", (10/100)'
0.100000
```